# Dealing with merge conflicts in Git Work Flow

Tags: git, git-workflow

I'm going to lay out the current scenario I'm having trouble with.

I've created three topic branches; Topic-A, Topic-B, Topic-C.

I'm done with all these branches, and am ready to merge them into the next branch to see how they work together.

Now all three topics have worked on a bunch of different files, but they have all worked on at some point File-A. When I go to merge them into next, I am obviously faced with a merge conflict.

Now, I can see with my own eyes what the issue is. I can see what I need to change in File-A to satisfy all three branches.

My question is, **how do I know handle this File-A in a clean mannor?**. My own personal dirty fix is to:

- Manually copy all three versions of File-A to notepad, and make a universal version of File-A that satisfies all three topic branch changes. Now I can move File-A into all three branches, and make a single commit in each branch.

That does not seem like a good way at all, as I'm creating three commits essentially doing the same thing in each branch. Not to mention the diff in each branch is going to show File-A changing completely, rather than the +additional changes I have made or -removals I have made.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to merge each of your branch sequentially.

Activate [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) (as [described here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere)) in order to record any merge conflict resolution done on `FileA`.
That way, you won't have to resolve *twice* the same conflict.

Comment: So you're saying I do what I said, manually fix the conflict by making a universal version of File-A. But I use rerere to record the change so that each time I go to merge a branch, it knows to use that universal file, thus avoiding a conflict?

Comment: @Rich if the conflict is the same, you won't have to resolve it again.